# Using VC++ dll using JNA

Tags: java, jna

I am using a *BTICARD.DLL*, which is the dll of *Arinc429* card. I need to write wrapper class in *Java* for the functions like `BTICard_CardOpen` for example.

I Had written an interface below **BTICardAPI.java**:

```
package NLIPjt;

import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
// import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public interface BTICardAPI extends  StdCallLibrary {
    BTICardAPI INSTANCE = (BTICardAPI) Native.loadLibrary("BTICARD", BTICardAPI.class);

    int BTICard_CardOpen(Pointer LPHCARD, int cardnum);
}
```

---

and my Java implementation prog 
**BTICardTest.java**:

```
package NLIPjt;

// import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public class BTICardTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BTICardAPI BTI1 = BTICardAPI.INSTANCE;

        int iErr;
        int CardNo  = 0;
        Pointer CardHandle = null;

        iErr = BTI1.BTICard_CardOpen(CardHandle, CardNo);

        System.out.println("Error Value: " + iErr);
    }
}
```

---

i get the following error in netbeans IDE:

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'BTICard_CardOpen': The specified procedure could not be found.
    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:245)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:566)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:542)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:528)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:228)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.BTICard_CardOpen(Unknown Source)
    at NLIPjt.BTICardTest.main(BTICardTest.java:14)
```

---

Looking for a solution!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) you need to make the library available. There are three ways to do this.

> Make your target library available to your Java program. There are
>   several ways to do this:
>
> The preferred method is to set the jna.library.path system property to
>   the path to your target library. This property is similar to
>   java.library.path, but only applies to libraries loaded by JNA.
>
> Change the appropriate library access environment variable before
>   launching the VM. This is PATH on Windows, LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux,
>   and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on OSX.
>
> Make your native library available on your classpath, under the path
>   {OS}-{ARCH}/{LIBRARY}, where {OS}-{ARCH} is JNA's canonical prefix for
>   native libraries (e.g. win32-x86, linux-amd64, or darwin). If the
>   resource is within a jar file it will be automatically extracted when
>   loaded.

Comment: I had included -Djava.library.path="C:\Windows\System32" in Run category of netbeans. Also i had included the path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152 under JAVA_HOME and updated PATH with %JAVA_HOME%\bin and C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: But still i get the same error. I didn't understand your last point. how to update the classpath, under the path win32-x86 in netbeans

Comment: Try adding the path to the target library not the path to the dir the library is in. See if that helps.

Comment: The last one is confusing. Say ./native was on the classpath. The a native library would need to be in ./native/win32-x86/lib.dll for that os and architecture.

Comment: You mean i have to add C:\Windows\System32\BTICARD.DLL in my interface code?

Comment: Try setting java.library.path to C:\Windows\System32\BTICARD.DLL instead of the dir.

Comment: Or jna.library.path as the documentation states.

Comment: After adding java.library.path in VM options in netbeans with full upto the dll file name i get the following error now. What next?

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class java
C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: You may have to set the main class in netbeans (for a netbeans project). Try right clicking on the file and setting it as the main class for the project.